# can't sendKeys to a file form field with selenium (js) if the file does not exist

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to fill in a form with a field for uploading a file, it works fine if the file exists, but somehow gets rejected when it doesn't.

```
const driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setLoggingPrefs({
  browser: 'ALL',
}).build();
await driver.executeScript(`document.write('<input type="file" id="testfile" name="testfile">');`);
await driver.findElement(By.id('testfile')).sendKeys('/does/not/exist');
```

I get this error:

```
WebDriverError: invalid argument: File not found : /does/not/exist
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse ([project]/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
    at parseHttpResponse ([project]/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:533:13)
    at Executor.execute ([project]/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

but I can't figure out where it the process it is checking if the file exists.  Is this a check that the browser does whenever you put something in that field, or a check that the selenium library is configured to make?  Or is it `chromedriver` that is doing the check?

Is there any way I can convince it to accept my non existant file name?  I am testing with remote selenium, so can't always make the file exists.  I don't need to submit the form, just fill it out.

(created the form field using `document.write` just for the sake of isolating the issue)